# uiwebview baseurl directory

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I have a directory images with lots of sub folders. 100,101 etc.,

How should my img tag and the uiwebview's base URL should be ?

```
<img href="/101/1000/238.jpg"> </img>?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have the following file structure:

```
index.html
101/a.jpg
102/b.jpg
```

The index.html can contain relative path to the images, e.g.

```
<img src="101/a.jpg" />
```

I hope that answers you question. If not, please give more detail about what you want to do, e.g. do you want to load a web page in the public domain, such as http://www.somesite.com?